# Where should I put chart-drawing code in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, drawing, code-organization

I've got some custom Ruby code for generating a chart (which will generally be displayed as an inline SVG in a "show" view) based on the contents of the model.

I'm wondering where I should put the drawing code.  As I see it, I could:

1. Put it in the model, so I can call `@my_object.chart_as_svg` in my view ... but this would diverge from MVC
2. Put it in a view, like `show.svg.erb`, and let my controller respond to format.svg
3. Put it in the controller as a separate action
4. Put it in a helper...

What's the prevailing wisdom on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think you might reuse the charting code for other things, make it a class, put it in `lib` and set it up so you can do something like this in your controller:

```
@chart = MyChart.new(:data => @my_object.data_method, :title => 'Foo Chart', ....)
send_data @chart.to_svg, ...
```

..

This way you can extend it with other options, add `.to_png`, etc without mucking up your model.

Comment: Yes, this thought also crossed my mind.  However, in this particular case, it's extremely specific to this single use-case, and I can pretty much guarantee that it's "reuse value" is approximately 0.

Comment: ... and yet, I think it's still the best way to go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IMO: A little bit of everything! Going down your list:

1. Your object has charts, so you should definitely have `@obj.chart`, but the chart isn't a part of the model - it may be created using model data, but it's not something that's a) restricted to that model or b) required by that model - so you do want it as part of a different package/module/object/etc
2. The Ruby object of the chart, IMHO, shouldn't "know" how to turn itself into an HTML view. That's the job of a partial - `_chart.svg.erb`, `_chart_typeB.svg.erb` - but it *should* "know" how to transform its information - counts, averages, percentages, etc etc. Partials then consume those different "formats".
3. I'm going to bet that at some point, you'll want to access the chart data directly via an API. Maybe you're turning your stuff into a platform, maybe you're doing AJAX updates to the current page; doesn't matter - you're going to eventually want some controller actions to directly access the chart data.
4. You should take anything complex out of the view partial and turn them into helpers, but the partial should still be responsible for the "styling". That is, the partial should generate the smallest atomic view of the chart - just the chart, nothing but the chart - but the partial should be whatever else you generally want to show when you want to include the chart in a web page.

Edit: Reading the other answer a bit, I've got a different assumption: I'm assuming your taking the chart information and generating the picture via Javascript on the webpage, rather than generating a picture on the server and serving it. If you are doing the latter, I'd make it as part of the chart class - it's a different "format" into which the data can be transformed.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the latter.  I think the issue with doing it as a partial is that the code ends up looking really ugly.  There's a lot of math involved in drawing the chart (finding coordinates, slopes of lines, etc), and mixing that sort of stuff into an erb or haml partial gives me the willies.  Going back and forth between countless little helper methods and calls to them from the partial doesn't seem much better - it would sure be nice to keep all the charting code in a single file.

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is that your view code should consume some simple JSON that, say, lists the points, and then your object code does all the heavy math. If the heavy math is involved in doing the actual drawing - well, then you should either make your own Javascript charting library with it, or use someone else's. There's a lot out there, some free, some not.

Comment: Yeah, the heavy math is involved in the actual drawing code.  I've done it in Ruby, rather than Javascript, because I'm much more comfortable in Ruby.  I spent an hour or so looking through various charting libraries (including several of the major Javascript ones), but this is such a specific type of chart that it looked like it was going to involve a lot of premature balding to get any of them to produce the rather customized output I was looking for.  It sounds like factoring the drawing code out as a class of it's own (sticking it in `lib/`) is probably closest to the right way to go.

Comment: Yep. You might also check out Opal, which compiles Ruby to Javascript, but I'm betting you make use of libraries that would prevent that option.